# Reloading a page and showing a new view in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my `AccountController` class I have this:

```
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel fpModel = null)
    {
        string method = HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

        if (method == "GET")
        {
            ViewBag.Status = "CREATE_TASK";
            ForgotPasswordViewModel model = this.ForgotPasswordManager.LoadForgotPasswordSettings();

            if (model != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ForgotPasswordMethod) && model.ForgotPasswordMethod.Trim().ToUpper() == "TASKS")
                return View(model);
        }

        if (method == "POST")
        {
             ViewBag.Status = "TASK_CREATED";
            this.CreateTask(fpModel);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ForgotPassword"); // Prob this is wrong? 
    }
```

Then in my View I have this:

```
@model Models.Account.ForgotPasswordViewModel

<div class="container" style="background-color: #f6f6f6">

    @if (ViewBag.Status == "CREATE_TASK")
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4 id="SearchWelcomeHeader">Password Request</h4>
        </div>

        using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
            // some textboxes to fill up a password request form go in here

            <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 20%">Submit</button>
            <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 20%">Cancel</button>
        }
    }

    @if (ViewBag.Status == "TASK_CREATED")
    {
        <p> Good Job ! You requested a new password! </p>
    }

</div>
```

So what I am trying to accomplish is this:  First they go to that page, fill up their password request form and they submit, so now it is a POST. So on a POST I go create some stuff in DB for them using that `this.CreateTask(fpModel);` in the code. But After then I want the page to be reloaded and show something new like "Success! We submitted your request", I will add an OK button later there too but currently something like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.Status == "TASK_CREATED")
{
    <p> Good Job ! You requested a new password! </p>
    ALSO A BUTTON, Will Add Later 
}
```

But this doesn't work, after they Submit, it reloads the page with a "GET" request and thus showing the form again. I want them to now see the other part of the page that was success message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RedirectToAction` method returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action

So, modify `return RedirectToAction("ForgotPassword");` to
`return View(fpModel);`

Comment: can you a bit explain how "return View(fpmodel) is different ?  it works, I just want to learn more now

Comment: `return View(model)` renders the view to the response using the model. This method passes a
`ViewResult` object to the ASP.NET MVC framework, which calls
the object's `ExecuteResult` method.